# Do we have a measurable set $E$, such that $\bar{E}=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $0<\mu\left(E\right)\leq\varepsilon$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, $\varepsilon$ be a positive real number. Do we have a measurable set $E$, such that $\bar{E}=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and  $0<\mu\left(E\right)\leq\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
E=\mathbb Q^2
\cup
B(0;r)
\quad\text{with}
\quad
0<r\leq\sqrt{\frac\varepsilon\pi}
$$

Comment: You are welcome! Remember that $\mathbb R^n$ is a [separable space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space), that is it admits a dense countable subset (take indeed $\mathbb Q^n$). Since points have null Lebesgue measure, and measures are sigma-additive, all countable sets have measure zero, and this trick works!